# How to remove app blinking issue with invalidatelater() in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This issue still exist with one of the most used items in shiny apps "DATATABLES". Final intention is to pull a data table from database and display over shiny app which refresh every sec. Here is the sample code which has the similar issue,

```
  library(DT)

  ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"),
  
  
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    
    invalidateLater(1000)
    
    mtcars
  })

  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Joe Cheng recommended [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/9faA5OUm2Hc)

```
tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating { opacity: 1.0 !important; }")
```

and it's works perfectly fine e.g. in ggplot2 charts, but not with datatables and leaflet map.

Is there any workaround how to remove blinking in this app? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They fixed this awhile ago. Using `DT::proxy` can remedy this issue.
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a answer to this specific question.  I would love to see a solution.

This is a workaround that may be useful.  You can render the table (or any Shiny output) from a reactive value that is **only updated when the queried data differs from the cached.**  The DT update will still cause a blink, but the blinks will only occur when the data is updated, not with every `invalidateLater` refresh.

In other words, if you want a 1 second refresh, but the data only updates every 10 minutes, you will only get a blink at 10 minutes.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  dat <- reactiveVal()
  
  query <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(1000 * 1) every second
    new_data <- dbReadTable(con, table)
    if (!identical(new_data, dat())) {
      dat(new_data)
    }
  })
  
  # I think observe is needed because there is no output calling query()
  observe(query())
  
  output$form <- renderDataTable(dat())
}
```

Comment: I think you simply need a `renderDataTable(dat() |> filter(datetime > Sys.time() - hours(1))`

Comment: I found the answer! See the link below!